# Add button as column in DataGridView

Tags: c#, button, datagridview, bindinglist

I'm currently working on a Winforms project that has a datagridview in it, on which I display my users list. I want to add (in addition to the basic parameters that are all int and string etc.) a button in the last column that will have an OnClick listener. Problem is, I don't have a dataSource and I'm working with a BindingList and BindingSource object; I've tried to add a button variable to the class that's displayed in the grid and it didn't work; I couldn't find a way to convert Button to DataGridViewCell. How do I add a button at the end of every row?

code:

```
var bindingList = new BindingList<userDisplay>(usersListDGV); //userDisplay has int and string variables
var source = new BindingSource(bindingList, null);
usersDGV.DataSource = source;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you set your grid to `AutoGenerateColumns = false` then add a column for each of the fields in your bindingsource and set the `DataPropertyName` appropriately so the column is bound. You can do this through the UI or in code. Then add a `DataGridViewButtonColumn` and handle the `CellClick` or `EditingControlShowing` event to wire up the click handler as mentioned [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/windows/en-us/c6f2daec-8e49-4137-94cb-764ed2d427aa/click-event-on-datagridviewbuttoncolumn).

Comment: Thank you very much! really helpful. Is there any way to add an image as the button's background though?

Comment: @FitzChivalry, well, probably but I suspect it would be a prohibitive amount of work. You might be better off using an image column and make it look like a button. Still a lot of work but you could handle the various cell events to provide button-like states.